# How to represent MVC Core Controller Action method same in Core Razor Pages 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I want to perform **Uploading & Downloading** from **Database** .In **MVC Core** its working properly but  **I am unable to convert MVC controller mathod into Razor Pages's Handler method.** How to do that .I will be very glad if anyone helped.Following are more details about my applications

**Controller methods of MVC Core**

```html
[HttpPost]  
  public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)  
  {  
      if (file == null || file.Length == 0)  
          return Content("file not selected");  
  
      var path = Path.Combine(  
                  Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",   
                  file.GetFilename());  
  
      using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))  
      {  
          await file.CopyToAsync(stream);  
      }  
  
      return RedirectToAction("Files");  
  }  
  
  public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)  
  {  
      if (filename == null)  
          return Content("filename not present");  
  
      var path = Path.Combine(  
                     Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  
                     "wwwroot", filename);  
  
      var memory = new MemoryStream();  
      using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))  
      {  
          await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);  
      }  
      memory.Position = 0;  
      return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));  
  }
```

**How To Represent above methods in Razor Pages**

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Razor Page follow steps below:

1. Add `File` Razor Page in `Pages`
2. Its content is

   ```
   public class FileModel : PageModel
   {
       public void OnGet()
       {

       }
       [BindProperty]
       public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
       [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
       public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadFileAsync()
       {

           return RedirectToPage("Index");
       }
       public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDownloadAsync(string filename)
       {
           if (filename == null)
               return Content("filename not present");

           var path = Path.Combine(
                       Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                       "wwwroot", filename);

           var memory = new MemoryStream();
           using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
           {
               await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
           }
           memory.Position = 0;
           return File(memory, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(path));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Its View is

   ```
   @page
   @model TestRazor.Pages.FileModel
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "File";
   }

   <h2>File</h2>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <form method="post" asp-page-handler="UploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="FormFile" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="FormFile" type="file" class="form-control" style="height:auto" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="FormFile" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Request for `OnGetDownloadAsync` is `https://localhost:44332/file?handler=download&filename=test.txt`
5. For Upload load file, turn to `https://localhost:44332/file`, and click upload button to upload file

For more information about Razor page, refer [Upload files to a Razor Page in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/upload-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2)